# Scraping a webpage including its subpages with JSDOM

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsdom

After going through a few tutorials, I've managed to serve up jsdom and express with a few lines of code and scraping the landing page of any url in the jsdom environment.

However, I can't seem to find any documentation on following through pages and links for further scraping.

Answer (score 0):

There's no recursive setting in jsdom. Just get all links from the top-level page and issues those that are within the same domain for new scrapes (recursively)

Answer (score -1):

try https://github.com/rc0x03/node-promise-parser

follow all links on example.com:

```
pp('example.com')
.find('a')
.follow('@href')
```